# does anyone have a sample pom and settings file used to site-deploy to confluence?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, xml-rpc, password-protection, confluence

I'm trying to use a Maven build to deploy to Confluence site using XML-RPC. 
I'm having trouble finding the right protocol to use in distribution management. It is password protected.

Answer (score 0):

Use one or both of the following:

- [Proxy Configuration](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Working+with+the+SDK#WorkingwiththeSDK-RunningBehindaCorporateFirewall)
- [Maven Server Authentication](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-settings/settings.html#class_server)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea. Maven Site does not fit so well for Confluence: they have a specific layout... you should customize a lot of things in order to create a site that could be uploaded to Confluence, and the deployment is only the tip of an iceberg.

Instead, I suggest you to think to a different content, written in Markdown (or asciidoc, ...). It's very easy to convert those type of content in HTML compatible with Confluence.

By the way, if you need to upload a maven site style I suggest you to take a look at [maven-confluence-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-confluence-plugin/): in the wiki pages you can find the configuration to apply to do what you need.
I'm working on a similar plugin too. It's called [confluence-maven-plugin](https://github.com/sixro/confluence-maven-plugin). However the phylosophy of my plugin is not to be able to upload site, but to upload simple Markdown documentation to a confluence, guided mainly by a `README.md` as you probably do when you work with Github/BitBucket/etc...